# Displaying big doubles in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of doubles and I want to see what are the exact numbers inside the vector I get in format long.

```
       1.0e+03 *

  -0.002202883146567
   1.182072110137121
  -0.002242966651629
  -0.000584787748712
   0.022251505213305
   0.037460846794487
```

Can I make some adjusment so that I can directly see the number, rounded to let's say the 5th or 6th element after the decimal point, whenever I type the name of the variable?

Comment: I think you're looking for "format ShortEng"

Answer (score 1):

```
 fprintf('%.6f\n', 0.037460846794487)
```

It'll round `0.037460846794487` to 6 decimal places as shown:

```
>> fprintf('%.6f\n', 0.037460846794487)
0.037461
```

Or you can also use `sprintf('%.6f\n', 0.037460846794487)` , particularly, if you want to save the rounded off output in a variable.

```
>> a=sprintf('%.6f\n', 0.037460846794487)

a = 
0.037461
```

and for the matrix you mentioned, you can make the following adjustment:

```
 %Your matrix
 A = 1.0e+03 * [ -0.002202883146567 ;
                  1.182072110137121 ;
                 -0.002242966651629 ;
                 -0.000584787748712 ;
                  0.022251505213305 ;
                  0.037460846794487 ];

 A = sprintf('%.6f\n', A)    %Adjusted to 6 decimal digits
```

Comment: Thats right, but I was wondering if there is a global modification to the matlab environment so that I see all variables rounded to the 6th decimal place